# from sklearn import DecisionTreeRegressor >> ImportError

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn

(1) Running Windows 8
(2) Downloaded and installed, Anaconda for Windows, PYTHON 2.7

(3) From Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install scikit-learn
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .....................
All requested packages already installed.
packages in environment at C:\Users\Joey\Anaconda2:
scikit-learn              0.17                np110py27_1
```

(4) Launched Spyder

(5) This is ok, and package is found.

```
import sklearn
```

(6) Tab completion (in Spyder) for sklearn, shows:

```
sklearn.base
sklearn.clone
sklearn.externals
sklearn.re
sklearn.setup_module
sklearn.sys
sklearn.utils
sklearn.warnings
```

(6) Therefore, when running a snippet as found in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ example.

```
from sklearn import DecisionTreeRegressor
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-5aa62260685f>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import DecisionTreeRegressor

ImportError: cannot import name DecisionTreeRegressor
```

(7)
Earlier, I noticed the same behavior using Enthought Canopy and also couldn't get scikit to work there either. As a result, I uninstalled every Python program and IDE I could find to try and clean my system before attempting Anaconda, as described above. I looked at many other posts and still could not get my system to work properly and suspect there's path, library, or version issue.

Comment: What page, exactly, told you to do `from sklearn import DecisionTreeRegressor`.

Comment: Yup, you're right, thanks. Fat fingered the copy-paste-edit from the docs and never looked back. Spent at least 8 hours on IDE installs, uninstalls, pip, etc, sigh... Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

Right way is:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
```

sklearn.**version** = 0.17

Answer (score 1):

decision tree algorithm is a module under Sklearn.tree
Try and import it in this manner, it should work

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
```

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn is well documented. Here is the [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) for the documentation.